# How to play user dial pad tone on my custom keypad press in android?

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager, android-keypad

In my app, I have a custom key pad and want to play tick tone on key press. The below code is giving me the sound.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
float vol = 1f; 
am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK, vol);
```

But I am looking to play the same tone which comes when user touches dial pad. How do I achieve it?

Comment: [`ToneGenerator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html) has presets for `TONE_DTMF_0` through `TONE_DTMF_9`.

Comment: @Michael This is what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of Michael comment. Posting here as it may help others :)

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING); // Highest Ring volume level is 7, lowest is 0
final ToneGenerator mToneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume_level * 14); // Raising volume to 100% (For eg. 7 * 14 ~ 100)
mToneGenerator.stopTone();
mToneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1, 100); // play sound for 100ms
```

Similarly for other keys, choose tone from `ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0` to `ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_9`

Comment: Thank you it helped